# Detect clipboard changes (Get-Clipboard -raw to variable for hashing?)

Tags: powershell, clipboard

is there a way to get the clipboard data, whatever type contents it may contain, into a variable for hashing?

I've been able to do it for specific format type, e.g.

```
$data = Get-Clipboard -Format Image
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$data.Save($ms, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)
$mystream = [IO.MemoryStream]::new([byte[]][char[]]$ms.GetBuffer())
$hash = Get-FileHash -InputStream $mystream -Algorithm SHA1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
write-host $hash
```

How can it be done with $data = Get-Clipboard -raw ?

Comment: You are asking how to hash a string copied to your clipboard right?

Comment: @Santiago, not just a string, any data that might be in the clipboard. I know how to do it for -format image, text and FileDropList separately but I'd like to be able to do it in one block of code for any kind of data, to watch for clipboard changes and for quick comparison with previous contents

Comment: You're asking for `-Raw` and that will be Format = Text or FileDropList so your question doesnt reflect what you're actually looking for. Each type will have their own way of writing the data to a memory stream. The best you can do is have multiple conditions checking the type you get from `Get-Clipboard` and run code based on that

Comment: @Santiago that's how I'm doing it now but I thought I could just get the raw data as a buffer and hash that, oh well. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: and there may be no actual data in the clipboard at all because apps can use lazy rendering to reduce memory and time consumption when not necessary

Comment: Actually there is no "raw" clipboard data to retrieve. The underlying clipboard API, [`GetClipboardData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata) requires you to specify a clipboard format. If you just want to check if clipboard content has changed, you may query the [clipboard sequence number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#querying-the-clipboard-sequence-number).

Comment: `Add-Type -NameSpace WinApi -Name ClipboardSeq -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern uint GetClipboardSequenceNumber();'; $sequenceNumber = [WinApi.ClipboardSeq]::GetClipboardSequenceNumber()`

Comment: @zett42 the GetClipboardData() can't be used in console apps. The code snippet in your second comment is what I was looking for, thanks! 
p.s. it works but the sequence number increments by more than 1 on each ctrl+c, sometimes by 10 or more, is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: The increase in sequence number correlates to the number of clipboard formats available in the clipboard, but its not just one increment per format. Making a screenshot increased the number on my system by 13, while only 7 formats were reported by `CountClipboardFormats()` . Couldn't find any actual documentation about how the number increments.

Comment: @zett42 hmm, interesting. Could you post the code snippet, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check if clipboard content has changed, you may query the [clipboard sequence number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#querying-the-clipboard-sequence-number).

Here is a complete code sample to detect clipboard changes by comparing the current sequence number with the previous one in a loop.

It also demonstrates how the increase in sequence numbers correlates with the number of formats currently stored in the clipboard.

```bash
# Define the p/invoke signatures for using the WinAPI clipboard functions.
Add-Type -NameSpace WinApi -Name ClipboardSeq -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern uint GetClipboardSequenceNumber();'
Add-Type -NameSpace WinApi -Name CountClipboardFmt -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int CountClipboardFormats();'

# Get the current clipboard sequence number
$lastSequenceNumber = [WinApi.ClipboardSeq]::GetClipboardSequenceNumber()

# Loop to poll for clipboard changes
while($true) {
   $newSequenceNumber = [WinApi.ClipboardSeq]::GetClipboardSequenceNumber()
   if( $lastSequenceNumber -ne $newSequenceNumber ) {
       $lastSequenceNumber = $newSequenceNumber
       "Clipboard has changed. New sequence number is: $newSequenceNumber"

       $numFormats = [WinApi.CountClipboardFmt]::CountClipboardFormats()
       "Number of formats in clipboard: $numFormats"
   }
   # Delay for one second to avoid CPU congestion.
   Start-Sleep 1
}
```

A typical output may look like this:

```text
Clipboard has changed. New sequence number is: 451
Number of formats in clipboard: 4
Clipboard has changed. New sequence number is: 456
Number of formats in clipboard: 4
Clipboard has changed. New sequence number is: 460
Number of formats in clipboard: 3
```

On the Win 10 system where I got this output the sequence number increment seems to be number of clipboard formats plus one. On another Win 10 system there was still a correlation, but a bigger difference (like 7 clipboard formats and an increase in sequence number of 13). I can't really explain these differences and there doesn't seem to exist a documentation. All that you can rely on is that the sequence number will increase if new data is put into the clipboard.